# Вычислить количество дней без массива и рекурсии

Tags: c

Мне необходимо вычислить количество дней между двумя датами, заданными в формате `DD/MM/YYYY`, включая начальный и конечный день на языке *C*, 
не используя массивы и рекурсию.

Как это сделать?

Comment: вычислил, не используя массивы и рекурсию. что делать дальше?

Comment: @war123, вы пробовали сами решить задачу? если да - покажите свой код.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а дальше показываете мне код

Comment: @PashaPash пока не получается

Comment: А если мне не нужны ни рекурсия, ни циклы, а массив заменяется на switch?

Comment: @Qwertiy покажите код?

Comment: @123wargo, показал.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Если обе даты даны по Грегорианскому календарю (т.н. новому стилю), то можно воспользоваться простой функцией для перевода тройки `(day, month, year)` в "число дней от Рождества Христова":

```
#define is_leap(year) ((year) % 4 == 0 && ((year) % 100 != 0 || (year) % 400 == 0))
int
ymd_to_ord(int year, int month, int day) {
    static int days_before_month[] = {
        0, /* не используется т.к. месяцы пронумерованы начиная с 1. */
        0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334
    };
    int y = year - 1;
    return day + days_before_month[month] + (is_leap(year) && month > 2) +
          y * 365 + y/4 - y/100 + y/400;
}
```

(Замечу что представленный код не годится для случая year <= 0, но идея использования Грегорианского календаря для таких дат представляется сомнительной.)

Теперь для вычисления количества дней между датами достаточно перевести обе даты в числа при помощи `ymd_to_ord` и вычислить ответ как `n2 - n1 + 1`, где `n1` (`n2`) это число полученное из более ранней (поздней) даты.

(Идея позаимствована из [C имплементации](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.0/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#l342) библиотеки `datetime` языка Питон.)

Если совсем без массивов, то `days_before_month[month]` можно заменить на вот такое выражение:

```
30 * month + (month + 5) * 4 / 7 - 35 + 2 * (month < 3)
```

или если хотите совсем всех запутать, на

```
(214 * month + 20) / 7 - 35 + 2 * (month < 3)
```

Можно избежать явной проверки года на високостность и месяца на "февральность" если считать дни с 1 марта а не 1 января.

```
int
ymd_to_mord(int year, int month, int day) {
    int a = (14 - month) / 12;
    int y = year - a;  /* лет с 1 марта 0-го года */
    int m = month + 12*a - 3;  /* месяцев -"- */
    return day + (153*m + 2)/5 + 365*y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400;
}
```

Значения `ymd_to_mord` отличаются от `ymd_to_ord` на константу которая сократится при вычислении разности в формуле `n2 - n1 + 1` для количества дней.

Comment: Хм.. У меня то же самое, но без массива, как просили.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Не вижу большой доблести в замене массива на switch, но если уж совсем без массивов, то см. добавление к моему ответу.

Comment: 1. Просили без массива - сделал без массива. 2. Есть подозрение, что оптимизатор тот switch сам на массив заменит. 3. Даже если нет, то вряд ли на этих 9 операциях можно сильно сэкономить по сравнению с 12 в swtch'е (rкстати, case 12 там лишний - забыл удалить). 4. Там не совсем замена. Там делается суммирование по месяцам (и можно туда же проверку високосности текущего года влепить), а в массиве суммы предпосчитаны.

Comment: @AlexanderBelopolsky: Доблесть заключается в том, чтобы обойти глупое ограничение в задании.

Comment: Да, а формулы вроде и покороче есть - на codegolf'е была задачка.

Comment: Какой смысл делать `is_leap` макросом?

Comment: @dzhioev: Никакого глубокого смысла нет.   Просто если сделать функцией, то код будет длиннее.   В коде по [ссылке](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.0/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#l197) `is_leap` функция.

Comment: @AlexanderBelopolsky: лучше функцию, чем такой макрос, который сломать проще простого (`is_leap(year + 1)`)

Answer (score 2):

1. Переводишь обе даты в дни от некоторой точки отсчёта.
2. Убеждаешься в правильной реализации проверки високосности года (особенно про кратность 100 и 400).
3. Вычитаешь из одного числа другое и добавляешь 1.

Хм.. А вообще, можно попробовать перевести в юниксовое время и не реализовывать перевод в дни самостоятельно.

Вместо массива можно использовать switch без break'ов.

---

http://ideone.com/nsxTYt

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned date(d, m, y)
{
    unsigned res = d + (m>2?y-1:--y)*365 + y/4 - y/100 + y/400;

    switch(m-1)
    {
        case 12: res += 31;
        case 11: res += 30;
        case 10: res += 31;
        case  9: res += 30;
        case  8: res += 31;
        case  7: res += 31;
        case  6: res += 30;
        case  5: res += 31;
        case  4: res += 30;
        case  3: res += 31;
        case  2: res += 28;
        case  1: res += 31;
    }

    return res;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned d1, m1, y1, d2, m2, y2, key, res;

    while (scanf("%u/%u/%u %u/%u/%u =>%u", &d1, &m1, &y1, &d2, &m2, &y2, &key) == 7)
    {
        res = date(d2,m2,y2) - date(d1,m1,y1) + 1;
        printf("%s %u %u\n", res==key?"OK":"FAIL", res, key);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Через юникс-время могут быть ошибки. Например если время это полночь и одна дата идёт по летнему времени, другая по зимнему - будет ошибка на 1 час, что выльется в 1 день.

Answer (score 0):

Как бы я сделал на **Java**:

1. Присваиваете стринговым переменным 2 даты
2. Задаете формат даты(**SimpleDateFormat** - это в java, в С должен быть аналог)
3. Парсите стринговые переменные в нужный формат
4. Получаете разницу в миллисекундах между первой датой и второй
5. Считаете количество дней

На С:

```
CTime t1( 1984, 10, 27, 22, 15, 0 ); // 10:15PM Nov 27, 1984
CTime t2( 1990, 3, 2, 22, 15, 0 );   // 10:15PM   March 2, 1990
CTimeSpan diff = t2 - t1;  // Subtract 2 CTimes
LONG d = diff.GetDays();   //
```

Вот еще: http://rsdn.ru/forum/alg/188079

Comment: Эм.. А разве в си есть встроенные классы для работы с датами?

Comment: @Qwertiy time.h не подходит? П.С.: отредактировал свой ответ

Comment: Хм.. Возможно, что-то в ней полезное есть, но вообще она что-то не очень похожа на то, что требуется.

Comment: Что-то этот сишный вариант использует странные функции. Стандартные в Си ТакойРегистрНеИспользуют. А ещё `diff.GetDays()` на си без плюсов не похоже. Конечно, в структуру можно положить указатель на функцию, но это явно не тот случай.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я не знаток С, так что ничего не могу сказать по этому поводу )

Comment: В задании было указание на использование  циклов или /и оператора for

Comment: @war123, так, чтобы я понимал, зачем использовать цикл? что в нем делать?

Comment: "Задачу можно решить путем написания множества инструкций и формул, но намного проще перебрать все дни от одной до другой даты в цикле и подсчитать количество итераций"
@Александр

Comment: @war123, почитайте по ссылке, что я добавил в ответ

Comment: @123wargo: Это легче, но намного медленнее. Зачем расходовать циклы машины без дела?

Comment: @VladD это не моя инициатива, так в задании прописано(
нужны самые базовые функции, операторы или циклы. в этом вся проблема

Comment: @123wargo: Ну, если в задании надо при помощи циклов умножить 2 на 3, вы тоже не будете пользоваться умножением, а будете складывать в цикле? В любом случае, у нас здесь не помощь в выполнении домашних заданий. В реальной жизни такие глупые ограничения не возникнут. Нам интересны реально полезные задачи, извините.

Comment: @VladD я не же прошу решать задание целиком, тем более мне вполне хватило той информации, которую здесь озвучили

Comment: @123wargo: А, ну тогда хорошо.

Comment: @VladD, а чем с циклом проще? Там же ещё дату на существование проверять придётся.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Проверка на существование концептуально проще, а так алгоритм-то один и тот же.